# pidgine messages to all

Tags: ejabberd, pidgin

```
ejabberd 16.01-2
client Pidgin 2.13.0 (libpurple 2.13.0)
```

I send message to all user if user is offline will not receive a message.

I want to send a message to everyone (mod_announce) via pidgin 2.13.0 (offline and online). Message to offline users is not saved.

```
mod_offline is running
auth_method: internal
```

Comment: Hey Piotr ! Could you elaborate a little by editing your post. It's not very clear what you're trying to do, what you already tried and what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks  Jérôme I will edit the post again.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the messages using mod_announce, it depends the method you use:

- This is sent only to online accounts: `example.org/announce/online`
- This is sent to all accounts, online and offline:
  `example.org/announce/all`

See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-announce

Answer (score 0):

I update ejabberd to 20.01 and all is OK now.